# UIkit 3.4.6 - Strong / Bold doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, uikit

I've been scratching my head :) The "bold" or "strong" doesn't
render properly in Chrome. I am using UIKit 3.4.6. Please, here's the simple [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jamesclavel/pen/VwvEVNZ) I created. You can open the link in Safari and Firefox it's working but in Chrome it doesn't work, the text doesn't go bold.

**Code:**

```
<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-large-top">Testing</h1>
<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-large-top"><strong>Testing STRONG</strong></h1>
<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-large-top"><b>Testing &lt;b&gt;</b></h1>
<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-large-top uk-text-bold">Testing UK-TEXT-BOLD</h1>
<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-large-top" style="font-weight: bold;">Testing STYLE-BOLD</h1>
```

Comment: The codepen works for me in Chromium v73. Which version are you testing in?

Comment: This issue https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/40862873?hl=en